# Error when accessing mysql database with sqlalchemy engine

Tags: python, mysql, class, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I've created a database in mysql and I'm trying to access it via python, using sqlalchemy. Please see below:

```
import mysql
from  mysql import connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import base
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnectionAbstract
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor

def return_connection_string(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
    try:
        connection_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + database_user + ':' + database_password + '@' + database_host + ':' + database_port + '/' + database_name
        print(connection_string)
        return connection_string
    except Exception as e:
        print('Encountered error while generating connection string for MySQL!')
        print(e)

t=return_connection_string('earningsdb','root','MyNewPass','127.0.0.1','3306')

engine = create_engine(t)

print(engine.table_names())
```

Everything works except for the last statement, which throws the following error

> engine.table_names() Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       engine.table_names()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 2136, in table_names
>       with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in
>   **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 1932, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
>       with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 2123, in contextual_connect
>       self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       return fn()
>
> File "C:\Users\userAnaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 403, in connect
>       return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 788, in _checkout
>       fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 532, in checkout
>       rec = pool._do_get()
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 1193, in _do_get
>       self._dec_overflow()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py",
>   line 66, in **exit**
>       compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py",
>   line 187, in reraise
>       raise value
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 1190, in _do_get
>       return self._create_connection()
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 350, in _create_connection
>       return _ConnectionRecord(self)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 477, in **init**
>       self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py",
>   line 671, in __connect
>       connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py",
>   line 106, in connect
>       return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
>   line 410, in connect
>       return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector__init__.py",
>   line 173, in connect
>       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 62, in **init**
>       super(MySQLConnection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of
>   type

I've looked at other posts with similar error, but could not figure out what exactly to do in order to solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest putting running the code in a python REPL shell, run run the pdb command before calling engine.table_names(), this will cause python to drop you into a debugger as soon as the exception gets raised, which will allow you to examine the stack and variables and figure out what is wrong

Comment: What versions of SQLAlchemy and mysql.connector? And does the error get thrown with those exact connection args provided in your example?

Comment: Here are the versions - SQLAlchemy: 1.2.7 / connector (imported from mysql): 2.2.2b1. With regards to the second question, yes. That is the error generated by that code. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi there. Python 3. |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]. Thanks for the help

Comment: 2.2.2 is a pretty old version of connector (2016). Are you able to upgrade to latest and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but I've decided to build the database on the pythonanywhere server. In this case the connector works fine. It must have been the old version of the connector or some other configuration problem I had.